# Vectorization of for loop over 1st dimension of tuple

Tags: python, vectorization

How would you best vectorize the for-loop below? Can it be vectorized?
It is not purely relevant to have the result as list, vector or tuple itself is also ok.

```
my_tuple = [[-0.125, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125, -0.125],
            [ 0.125,  0.125,  0.125, 0.125 , 0.125 , 0.125],
            [ 0.25 ,  0.25 ,  0.25 , 0.25  , 0.25 ,  0.25 ]]
my_list = []
constant = 2
for i in range(len(my_tuple)) :
    my_list.append(my_tuple[i][constant].sum())
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data with expected input and output, thanks, it is unclear what the variables are, you named it `tuple` but is it a list of `tuple` or what exactly

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what `tuple` looks like. Is it a 2(or more)-dimensional array?

Comment: looks like np.cumsum()[https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html] will be helpful, if you cast your tuple into np array

Comment: @PWillms your code wouldn't work for that `my_tuple` because it's only 2-dimensional and you cannot get the `.sum()` of the `[i, j]`th element of a 2D array (the element is a single number). Does the `my_tuple` in my answer make more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Note: I've replaced `list` and `tuple` with `my_list` and `my_tuple` to prevent shadowing python's inbuilt classes `list` and `tuple`.

You'd probably need to use `numpy` or some other library that does vectorized calculations.

In your case, it looks like `my_tuple[i]` is a 2+ dimensional list . `my_tuple[i][constant]` gives you *one element* of said list. and then `.sum()` calculates the sum of everything in the `constant`th element of `my_tuple[i]`.

Say your `my_tuple` is purely numeric, and looks like so:

```
my_tuple = (
    [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
    [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
    [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],
    
    [[12, 13, 14, 15],
    [16, 17, 18, 19],
    [20, 21, 22, 23]],
    
    [[24, 25, 26, 27],
    [28, 29, 30, 31],
    [32, 33, 34, 35]],
    
    [[36, 37, 38, 39],
    [40, 41, 42, 43],
    [44, 45, 46, 47]],

    [[48, 49, 50, 51],
    [52, 53, 54, 55],
    [56, 57, 58, 59]]
)
```

You could cast it into a `numpy` array like so:

```
tup_arr = np.array(my_tuple)
print(tup_arr.shape)
```

Then, you want each element of `my_list` to be equal to the sum (along the last axis) of the `constant` column of each "chunk" of `my_tuple`.

```
constant = 2
vec_sum = tup_arr[:, constant, :].sum(axis=-1)
print(vec_sum) # Outputs array([ 38,  86, 134, 182, 230])
```